# Export JsHint settings

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How to export JsHint settings from PhpStorm/WebStorm?

There are all kinds of categories available which one does it fit in? I have tried all of them but have worked for me...

Comment: I mean `export settings` of the IDE to be able to share it across my team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These settings are not IDE-wide and thus can't be exported via File | Export settings; these are your project preferences, they are stored in `.idea/jsLinters/jshint.xml`.

Comment: Thx lena. I have used `jsHintConfig` in the end. My solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810147/run-jshintconfig-in-phpstorm