# Run jsHintConfig in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In PhpStorm in `file -> settings -> Language & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> JSHint` I have checked `Enable` and `Use config files`. I have tried both options for `location`. For custom configuration file I used a path leading to my `package.json` yet I am not able to override jshint settings. It seems like if the IDE was looking somewhere else...

How to tell PhpStorm/WebStorm that it should use `jsHintConfig` from `package.json`?

If I use

```
"jshintConfig": {
  "eqeqeq": true,  // true: Require triple equals (===) for comparison
}
```

The IDE doesn't complain of `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the JSHint version from **2.8.0 (Bundled)** to **2.9.1** and use **Location -> Default** settings.